# Which JQuery version is suitable for all jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue on using JQuery versions:
Which JQuery version is suitable for all functions of jquery.

In my website designing:
I use the following js version for Contact Form validation:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
```

I use the following js version for page smooth scroll:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

If I use both: The contact form is works, scrolling not works. What shall I do for this?

Comment: could you please provide code sample or fiddle?

Comment: @VilasKumkar Which version is suitable for all functions?

Comment: If you need to support IE9 and lower you should really use jQuery 1.11.1. If something does not work with that version, fix it or replace it.

Comment: There's no such thing. What do you mean?

Comment: Only use one at a time - not advisable to include two different versions at the same time.  You need to use the most recent version that supports the functions you need (ideally you need to use the most recent version full stop, as it will contain bug fixes).

Comment: @StylerKishore I guess you need to use jquery migrate js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank to Stack Overflow Team and all of you first,
I found a solution to solve the issue.

Jquery's .noConflict();

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var jq211 = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var jq20 = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
```

I followed the function. Now no issues in using the versions of Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You just need one of your script statements as they both doing the same thing.

The difference is just if you want to load the script from your server or the google server.

Both versions are doing what you want. I would suggest to use the latest Version. If you want to support older browser (like IE8) you have to use 1.x, otherwise use 2.x

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's APIs change over time, and jQuery is not 100% back compatible. I recommend trying a recent version of jQuery (2.1.x, or 1.11.x if you need to support old browsers) along with [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/), which brings some old jQuery features back for migration purposes. If that still doesn't work, update your jQuery plugins and ensure that your third and first party code are both using compatible versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix it otherwise, you should look into using the `.noConflict()` method. If you do that, you can use several different versions of jQuery in one page.

Please refer to http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page for more info :)